# How to configure Cisco ASA to expose SFTP server to external interface?

Tags: cisco-asa

We recently upgraded from "prosumer" equipment to Cisco ASA routers, and I am trying to learn some basic administration of the devices. The reason this will sound like a newbie question is ... well ... because it is.

I have configured a nat-ssh service for port 22, following the pattern for nat-http and nat-https that were pre-installed by our vendor.

I had no issues configuring the prior equipment to route FTP requests to my FTP server, but the Cisco ASA is a little more complex to configure. Where can I find step-by-step instructions for configuring the Cisco ASA to route SFTP traffic from the internet to an internal server in ASDM?

The Packet Trace test fails because the NAT rule is not catching the packets, and they are falling through to the final "deny all" rule that is configured.

Thank you in advance.

**ACL Rule definition:**
[image: ACL Rule definition]

**Packet Trace Results:**
[image: Packet Trace Results]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should configure the global IP as destenation in the ACL not the private IP and you can check the below link for more information: 
[Configure ASA  Port Forwarding with NAT](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/ip/network-address-translation-nat/118996-config-asa-00.html#anc8)

Comment: Gotta learn to think in "cisco".  thanks!